# The process cannot acces the file as it is being used by another process C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a .Net console application. I would like to catch any exceptions occur during the execution and  write it to a text file. If there is any entry on the file before, I am getting

> The process cannot acces the file as it is being used by another process.

I tried closing the connections as well below but still it's showing the same error.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writeerror = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_txtError))
            {
                writeerror.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                writeerror.Flush();
                writeerror.Close();
             }
}
```

Note: At the start of the program execution I am deleting the file and regenerate if any error occurs.

Comment: And all your write to this file are inside a using statement like here?

Comment: It would make more sense to show the whole snippet

Comment: what happens inside the `try` statement?

Comment: Error message seems pretty straightforward. Do you have a copy of this error log open in notepad or something similar? As an aside, logging ex.ToString() would probably be much more helpful.

Comment: @Steve Yes. If that is not right please let me know what should I change in my code

Comment: it might be worth-while to use a logging library like log4net

Comment: from what you've showed here it seems same as error says, the stream is used by another process. Try to use different stream, if that works, you should check all StreamReader/Writer using _txtError

Comment: @jonathana Try block does dofferernt things and it wont refer this txt file. The problem is Im using the same statements across multiple catch blocks and if the Txt file is already written with some message Im getting this error when it goes to a catch block again

Comment: Most likely you've forgotten to close the file somewhere. Make sure you're using `using` on all of your `StreamWriter`s. Better yet, create a simple helper function somewhere that encapsulates that behavior, and simply send it the line to log.

Comment: *Instead of using the StreamWriter, you may save the logs using the instruction* :  "System.IO.File.AppendAllText(mylogfilename,ex.Message+Environment.NewLine)".

Comment: The issue is resolved. Thank you all for jumping in and gave good ideas to troubleshoot the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found where was the issue. At the end of all the functions I had a send e-mail function which send the log file as attachment to a group. The problem is from my workstation I can't send emails. Once the deploy the code in server, e-mail task will function as it's supposed to do. I had a similar catch stmt for Send email task and when it fails it tries to write the same error file I'm ATTACHING in the email task. Once i removed the catch logic the issue is resolved. Whew!! I know.. It's a stupid mistake! :( Learnt something from this mistake